Riemann-Roch theorem about Riemann's viewpoint
Is there a paper or article that details the background of Riemann-Roch theorem and his own handwritten manuscript of his thoughts on the theorem? When I searched on Google, I found that there were many modern-day motives for the Riemann-Roch theorem rather than Riemann's own thoughts. I'm curious about the background or motives of Riemann's thoughts during his time.

See Gray, The Riemann-Roch Theorem and Geometry, 1854-1914, "The history of the Riemann-Roch Theorem, from its discovery by Riemann and Roch in the 1850's to its use by Castelnuovo and Enriques in from 1890 to 1914."

@Conifold Hello, thank you for your comment. By the way, I read the paper linked to the comment while searching on Google. However, I am curious about the thoughts or ideas that Riemann had about the Riemann-Roch theorem, as mentioned in Roch[1865], which is on page 2 of the linked paper. Or, I am curious about Riemann's remarks that provided the basis for mathematicians after Riemann to make such inferences.

Riemann's original paper seems to be quite clear about this.
